# Get variable from php object parent

Tags: php, variables, object

I am trying to make the jump towards object orientated php. I'm building my own MVC framework from the ground up because I like to have full control and I figure it's a good learning exercise to do.

This is my router which I use to route to different folders according to the name (I have an autoloader function in the index file):

```
class controller_router
{
    public $controller;
    public $action;
    public $id;
    public $freetext;

    //set the url path variables
    public function __construct($controller,$action,$id,$freetext)
    {
        $this->controller = $controller;
        $this->action = $action;
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->freetext = $freetext;
    }

    //instantiate the main controller according to url
    public function instantiateMainController()
    {
        $controller_name = 'controller_'.$this->controller;
        $controller = new $controller_name;
    }
}
```

My blog controller looks like this (just testing to see if I can get the action):

```
class controller_blog
{   
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo $this->action;
    }
}
```

**My question is - how do I get the action variable from the parent (the router)?**

The command `echo $this->action;` does not appear to work!

Also, any other improvements you could suggest? I am a newbie!

Comment: Of course it doesn't, you don't pass the properties from the controller_router to the controller_blog

Comment: To clarify, is one of these classes supposed to be extending the other? Or both extending a base controller class? None of the above?

Comment: I am just declaring the blog_controller inside the router_controller.....so not sure - I am newbie :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should pass your object to new object.

```
$controller = new $controller_name($this);

//...

class controller_blog
{   
    public function __construct($router)
    {
        echo $router->action;
    }
}
```

Comment: hmmm this is interesting. So I can pass all variables as a single object then like that? wow ok..

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do that *in code* - but first you need to do that *in mind*. That means - you need to realize, what is the structure of your application. What structure has each entity? How each entity is implemented in class? How entities are related and how that is implemented in code?

For example, one of options can be inherit your action from parent class. But first you'll need to make your `controller_blog` child of `controller_router`. This may have sense - but are they related in such way - is up to you to decide. You can do this with:

```
class controller_blog extends controller_router
{   
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo $this->action;
    }
}
```

-so you'll have one class that will extends another.

But may be they're not related such way? Then you'll need to inject dependency into your blog controller. For example

```
class controller_blog
{   
    public $action;

    public function __construct(controller_router $router)
    {
        $this->action = $router->action;
    }
}
```

-since you've not specified your structure, you'll need to decide what is more correct by yourself.

Comment: ah problem is that I can't make it a fixed extension of router. In some cases it may be blog_controller, others it may be page_controller, etc.....dynamic thing

Comment: So that's the point. You need to decide what is correct and fits your structure. And to do that, you need to clearly understand your structure

Comment: I think I will have one object create a new object outside of it because it is required to be dynamic according to the url. Ty for help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Pass variables from the `controller_router` to the `controller_blog` as arguments of the constructor of `controller_blog`.